# Certifying Copy of US Passport for UK Bank

Tags: united-kingdom, certification

I am a former expat in the UK. I have returned to the US and now need to refinance the house I bought while in the UK. The UK bank requires a certitfied copy of my passport which would be simple if I still lived there. US notaries will not certify the true likeness of the photograph, only the document. Who in the US can certify this? Can US lawyers, doctors, etc. do the same thing as UK ones?

Answer (score 2):

You *really* need to ask the bank who they consider an acceptable certifier.  To pick an example I used within the last couple of years, the Skipton Building Society lists:

- Solicitor
- Chartered accountant
- Barrister
- Councillor (Local or County)
- Justice of the Peace
- The Post Office
- Local Government Officer
- Member of Parliament
- Doctor
- Police Officer
- Financial Services Intermediaries
- (BFPO) Officer of the armed services

Nowhere do they say it needs to be a *British* doctor or police officer.  I would be very surprised if they didn't accept a member of Congress (probably including State Governments) etc.

However, I repeat - you need to check the requirements of the bank *you* are using.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to imagine you're the first person to face this challenge. I'd ask the bank how they've dealt with this issue (UK non-residents selling UK property) in the past.

Failing a good answer, consider sending your passport to the bank by courier (FedEx, DHL, etc), and paying the bank to return the passport to you in the same manner.

Comment: I don't think using a courier is good advice.

Comment: It may well be superior to having to travel back to the UK in person to accomplish the physical presentation of the passport.

Comment: @MartinBonner, FWIW the UK Passport Office uses DHL to send passports to British expats.

Comment: @David Yes - but given there are *lots* of people who can certify, it seems completely pointless.  (Not the down-voter by the way.)

Comment: @MartinBonner I don't disagree, but who know whether the bank would accord foreign officials the same trust as domestic UK ones.

Comment: That's an *easy* question: The bank would know.  Hence the first and last sentence of my answer.  (But my experience suggests that they will.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Indeed so...as I responded ('tho not as precisely as you just did) in the first sentence of my answer above.